# Windows 7 batch file date Issue

Tags: date, windows-7, batch-file

I worked in windows XP and moved to windows 7 now. Used batch files to build.  Now it doesn't work.

Windows XP:

```
echo %DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~10,4%

02-10-2011
```

Windows-7:

```
echo %DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~10,4%

2--01-
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: replacing %date% by %date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2% worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet the output/format of %DATE% has changed - it's affected by locale/regional setting.

Just do an `echo %DATE%` to see if the format has changed from WinXP to Win7.

Comment: It is : echo %DATE% ---> 10-02-2011   . Thanks :)

Comment: echo %DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2%-%DATE:~6,4%
02-10-2011

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. But when I tried this:

```
SET DATF=2011-10-02
ECHO %DATF:~4,2%-%DATF:~7,2%-%DATF:~10,4%
```

it displayed:

```
-1--0-
```

So my guess is in your Windows 7 environment `%DATE%` must be returning the date in a different format from what it used to be in WinXP. You might want to change the script or to change locale settings for date/time.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out. The problem is that Win7 are counting string from 0 instead of 1 in XP, so the solution is:

XP

```
echo %DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~10,4%
```

WIN7

```
echo %DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~6,2%-%DATE:~9,4%
```

Try it, this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your time setting, the time format may be different.
Try simply this line on both:

> echo %DATE%

The most used are DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY.

Than, if different, parse your string as needed.